# "expected ')' before '*' token" - On linux but not on Windows

Tags: c, gcc

Need help compiling in C. When using GCC at home (Windows, 3.4.5), the code compiles fine (even with -Wall). When using the uni's GCC (4.3.3, debian), I keep getting the following message - "expected ')' before '*' token". What might be the matter? (Needless to say, compiling it on school's farm is a must).

The exact error message:
MatrixMultiplactionMacro.h:5: error: expected ')' before '*' token

```
    #ifndef _MATRIXMULTIPLACTIONMACRO_H
#define _MATRIXMULTIPLACTIONMACRO_H

void pseudoMain(
            member* (*__allocateMember)(), 
            void (*__freeMember)(member*), 
            char* (*__memberToString)(member*), 
            void (*__setToZero)(member*), 
            void (*__multiplyMembers)(member*, member*, member*), 
            void (*__addMembers)(member*, member*, member*), 
            void (*__writeToMember)(char*, member*),
            void (*__duplicateMember)(member*, member*)
            );

#endif
```

The problematic line, therefore: 
         member* (*__allocateMember)(),

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, it might help to upgrade your compiler at home. I believe GCC has had some major changes between 3.4 and 4.3. It might also help to compile everything with the `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` options on. You can leave off `-Werror` if you don't mind the warnings, but it does help to at least see them.

Comment: He's using the old compiler because both MinGW and Cygwin shipped 3.4 by default until recently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument to pseudoMain is a pointer to a function returning 'member', which isn't a C or C++ keyword, and I don't see a definition for it.  Perhaps you are missing a #include?

Comment: Thank you, Warren. It was a missing link, after all. I feel foolish.